# Javascript split creating an error for the first record

Tags: javascript

Check this Jfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/TyJy4/9/

Here there is an array of users.If the username is right,you are allowed to go to the password field.The code works fine except **when I type the first record(user) in the username for the first time.**

Conditions when the `user` record works

1. When I type user and space, then tab(here it will throw error saying it does not exist in db.)then backspace, then tab it, goes to the password field.
2. When I type `user2`(or any other users except the first one) and then type `user`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the code to remove the readonly before you return true. See if making that change solves the problem for you (it appeared to for me):

```
for (var j=0; j<names.length; j++){
if(names[j].localeCompare(x)==0){
        z.removeAttribute("readonly", 0);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The above can be shortened to:

```
if(names.indexOf(x) != -1){
    z.removeAttribute("readonly", 0);
    return true;
}
```

This uses the built-in `indexdOf()` which is probably written in C++, which should give it a performance boost over your `for` loop.

Comment: it worked....but i dont get why it works for the rest of the records except the first one?

Comment: I understand why it doesn't work for the first one, but I'm equally unsure why it does work for the rest. I updated my answer to give you an alternative (and shorter) way of writing that part.